# how to add a first line to a text file in node.js (using fs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, save, text-files, edit

I'm trying to add a **first** line to an existing text file using node.js.

My actual code looks as follows: 
var fs = require('fs');

```
fs.appendFile('test.txt', 'X        Y', function (err) {

});
```

The text: 'X        Y' is not added as first line, but last.

It would help a lot, if you have an idea, how to add my line as first of the document! :-)

Greetings, 
JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The file systems are not designed that way. You have to write your line first to a temp file and then append the content of you file. Then rename/move your temp file to the name of the original one. (And be sure there was no error when writing, otherwise you loose the content of the original file.)

Comment: i was looking for same, but your answer hurt me

Comment: Any better idea welcome. Can we talk about removing lines from the beginning of a file, too? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this, and here is my solution

```
const file = 'test.txt'
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    const newData = data.replace(/^/, `text to the first line`)
    fs.writeFile(file, newData, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Saved!')
    })
  }
)
```

So first, you have to read the file. After that, you can add your string to the first line with replace method.